# Wix projects not compiling when I build solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I just inherited a project that uses Wix for Installation setups. I noticed that when I right-click the solution and select Build, the Wix projects don't build as well. I have to right click each Wix project and click Build. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, WiX projects will not be built when building the 'Any CPU' platform because Windows Installer packages are CPU-specific. As a result, you need to use the following steps to update the solution build configuration to include your WiX project and its dependencies as part of a Team Foundation Build.

1. In the solution, open Configuration Manager (Build | Configuration Manager).
2. Set the 'Debug' configuration as the active configuration.
3. Select the 'x86' platform that you plan to build from the drop-down list.
4. Ensure that the WiX project is checked in the 'Build' column.
5. Ensure that any project references that the WiX project uses are also checked in the 'Build' column.
6. Set the 'Release' configuration as the active configuration.
7. Repeat steps 3-5 to ensure that the WiX project and its dependencies will build for the 'Release' configuration.
8. If you plan to build the 'x64' platform, repeat steps 3-7 for the 'x64' platform.
9. Close Configuration Manager and save the solution.

Source: [WIX Toolset Documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/wix_with_team_build.html)